# how to map 1 source data to 3 target data in xslt 1.0 in bpel

Tags: xslt-1.0, bpel

I have a source xml like this  ..

```
   <root>
    <rootElement>
  <Name>Name1</Name>
  <ID>001</ID>
  <element1>A</element1>
  <element2>B</element2>
  <element3>C</element3>
  <elementName>First</elementName>
</rootElement>
<rootElement>........</rootElement>
  </root>
```

I want a target xml like

```
 <root>
 <rootElement>
 <name>Name1</name>
    <id>001</id>
  <element1>A</element1>
  <element2></element2>
  <element3></element3>
  <processedFlag>N</processedFlag>
  <elementName>First</elementName>
    </rootElement>
     <rootElement>
 <name>Name1</name>
  <id>001</id>
  <element1></element1>
  <element2>B</element2>
  <element3></element3>
  <processedFlag>N</processedFlag>
  <elementName>First</elementName>
    </rootElement>
        <rootElement>
    <name>Name1</name>
  <id>001</id>
  <element1></element1>
  <element2></element2>
  <element3>C</element3>
  <processedFlag>N</processedFlag>
  <elementName>First</elementName>
    </rootElement>
  </root>
```

means for each record, I need 3 `<rootElement>` tags.

I have tried with `oraext:create-nodeset-from-delimited-string` but it is not working for more than one elements. Please help.

Comment: The output you show us is not XML: you cannot have a prefix (`top:`) without binding it to a namespace.

Comment: Hi Michael,  I have corrected the target xml. I just want the logic..

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="rootElement/element1 | rootElement/element2 | rootElement/element3"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element1 | element2 | element3">
    <rootElement>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../Name | ../ID "/>
        <element1>
            <xsl:value-of select="current()[self::element1]" />
        </element1>
        <element2>
            <xsl:value-of select="current()[self::element2]" />
        </element2>
        <element3>
            <xsl:value-of select="current()[self::element3]" />
        </element3>
        <processedFlag>N</processedFlag>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../elementName"/>
    </rootElement>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y99